# HTTP POST request from app works on iPhone but not on Android phone

Tags: android, ios, iphone, ionic-framework, http-post

In my ionic app I have a POST request to do login. This works fine on an iPhone but when I test the app on an Android phone the server returns a 404 Not Found error.

My code for making the HTTP request looks like this:

```js
    loginUser: function(email,password) {
      var em = email.replace(/\s/g,'');
      var pw = password.replace(/\s/g,'');
      var url = apiDomain + '/api/v1/user/login/';

      if (em && pw) {
        return $http.post(url, {
          auth: {
            email: em,
            password: pw
          }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
          alert('login success. response = '+JSON.stringify(response));
          return response;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
          alert('login fail. response = '+JSON.stringify(response));
          return -1;
        });
      }
    },
```

Can anyone think of a reason why this would work on an iPhone but not on an Android phone?

The text shown by the alert() in the errorCallback is:

```html
login fail. response = {
"data":"",
"status":404,
"config":{
  "method":"POST",
  "transformRequest":[null],
  "url":"http://cues-server-dev.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/v1/user/login/",
  "data":{
    "auth":"{
      "email":"aa@aa.aa",
      "password":"alcohol"}},
  "headers":{
    "Accept":"application/json,text,plain,*/*",
    "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},
  "statusText":"Not Found"}
```

I am at a loss to understand why this works on an iPhone but not an Android phone.

Comment: * Initially check whether internet permission is given or not.

Comment: All other apps on the Android phone are using internet fine.

Comment: * Need to have Internet permission for the Android-App with which you are facing problem. It does't matter all other app are having internet-permission.

Comment: Yes it does have internet permission

Answer (score 0):

It may be to do with the URL prefix. Have you tried using:

```
apiDomain = @"https://cues-server-dev.elasticbeanstalk.com"
```

or

```
apiDomain = @"http://www.cues-server-dev.elasticbeanstalk.com"
```

or some other variant.

Comment: No joy there unfortunately